# How to include from directory?

Tags: compilation, include, compiler-warnings

I am trying to add a project's (call it `b`) code to a different project(call it `a`). Both projects are compile and run separately. I just copied the folder of project `b` into project `a`'s folder. In project `a`'s `Makefile`, I added the lines to compile project `b` with it. It compiles fine. Now I want to use `b`'s code. But when I try to `#include "/bfolder/somefile.h"`, it cannot find the file. What am I missing about this? If I can just `#include "somefileinsamedirectory.h"`, why can't I do `#include "/bfolder/somefile.h"`?`

This is a 's Makefile that I have edited to include the irobot_driver code.

```
INCLUDE = -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/home/sterling/irobot_driver
CC=g++ 
CFLAGS=-w -D LINUX -fpermissive 
CFLAGS_R= -w -D LINUX -O3 -fpermissive 
CFLAGS_D=-w -D LINUX -fpermissive 
OBJ= obj
OBJ_DEBUG= obj_debug
OBJDIR= release
SRCDIR= src

LDFLAGS= -L/usr/X11R6/lib$(LIBSELECT) -lGL -lfltk -lfltk_gl -lXext -lX11 -lglut -lGLU -lfltk_images

SOURCES_RAW=codeprofiler.cpp gametimer.cpp timer.cpp timeprofile.cpp vector4.cpp matrix.cpp agent.cpp agentcontroller.cpp dummy.cpp evader.cpp pursuer.cpp goal.cpp player.cpp graphdata.cpp graph.cpp cubiccoefs.cpp segment.cpp trajectory.cpp anode.cpp arrayvector4.cpp color.cpp drawcomponent.cpp drawcontroller.cpp flags.cpp global.cpp map_analyzer.cpp minheap.cpp node.cpp quadtree.cpp queue.cpp results.cpp sensor.cpp settings.cpp utility.cpp world.cpp gui.cpp main.cpp logger.cpp parameters.cpp counter.cpp polygon.cpp line.cpp

TARGET:= pursuit_evasion
TARGETD:= pursuit_evasion_d
TARGETP:= pursuit_evasion_p
TARGETW32:= pursuit_evasion_w32

OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES_RAW:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS:=$(patsubst %.o,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(OBJECTS))

SOURCES:=$(SOURCES_RAW)
SOURCES:=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp, $(SOURCES))

OBJ_DEBUG:=$(SOURCES_RAW:.cpp=.o)
OBJ_DEBUG:=$(patsubst %.o,debug/%.o, $(OBJ_DEBUG))

OBJECTS_P:=$(SOURCES_RAW:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS_P:=$(patsubst %.o,profile/%.o, $(OBJECTS_P))

OBJDIR=obj

all: $(TARGET)

#--- Release 
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -w -D LINUX $(INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
    cd /home/sterling/irobot_driver; sudo make -j2

release/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS_R) -o $@ 

#--- Debug
debug: $(TARGETD)

$(TARGETD): $(OBJ_DEBUG)
    $(CC) -w -D LINUX $(INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
    cd /home/sterling/irobot_driver; sudo make -j2

debug/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -g $< $(CFLAGS)-o $@ 

#-- Profile
profile: $(TARGETP)

$(TARGETP): $(OBJECTS_P)
    $(CC) -w -g -pg -D LINUX $(INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

profile/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -g -pg $< $(CFLAGS)-o $@ 

win32: $(TARGETW32)

$(TARGETW32): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -w -D WIN32 $(INCLUDE_W32) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm -f release/*.o
    rm -f debug/*.o
    rm -f profile/*.o
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(TARGETD) $(TARGETP)
    cd /home/sterling/irobot_driver; make clean;
```

The #include "/the/whole/path/to/a/file"  that works is -

```
#include "/home/sterling/irobot_driver/robot_driver_agent.h"
```

Comment: Is bfolder at the root of your file system?

Comment: Your compiler/makefile/whatever should have some option to include additional "include" directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but when you declare the path starting with `/some/path/to/file.h` it's going to really look for the file at `/some/path/to/file.h`. If instead you want the `bfolder/somefile.h`, remove the `/` from the beginning.

Also, in general, if `b` is a library that you want to use, it is best to keep it in whatever folder it resides, and include and link using the `-I`, `-L` and `-l` options of gcc, or similar options of other compilers. This way, if you update `b` you don't need to copy it to every project that uses it.

Comment: Okay. I took the folder out and changed the Makefile to go where b 's original path is and compile there. It does this fine. I tried to add a -I/full/path/to/b, but it still cannot find the file.

Comment: so now I have a symbol that looks like INCLUDE = -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/path/to/b

Comment: The line where you write `g++ ....` in the Makefile, make sure you say `g++ ... $(INCLUDE)`

Comment: If it still doesn't work, I'd double check the name of the file, see if there are any trailing whitespaces etc. You could definitely try (in a console) to edit the file `/path/to/b/somefile.h` and see if you can open it in shell. If not, then `tab` your way to the path and file see where you made a mistake

Comment: Hmm...the projects have some of the same file names like utility.h and agent.h. Could that be a reason something is going wrong or does the compiler know which file for which build?

Comment: If the same file name appears in two paths, yes it most certainly could get confused!

Comment: Well I changed the names that are the same and I still cannot find the file. I am able to do #include "/the/whole/path/to/file"  and that works fine..

Comment: Post the working `#include "/the/whole/path/to/file"` and the not working Makefile in your original question so that I could take a look!

Comment: You should put the `$(INCLUDE)` where you compile (with `-c`) not where you link (the targets)! (Side note: you don't need space after `-D`, also, double check this, but I thought you are not supposed to change `CFLAGS`)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#include "bfolder/somefile.h"
```

You are including a leading slash in `"/bfolder/somefile.h"`, which means `/bfolder` would be in the *root* directory.

Comment: Okay, that is good to know but it still cannot find the file when I take away the initial / or if I do ./

Answer (score 0):

`#include "/bfolder/..."` would be implying that bfolder is in the root directory of your computer's file system. If bfolder is in the same directory as your source code, then you would just want `#include "bfolder/somefile.h"`